# Determine the size of the biggest image in a set - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 5 different images (which can be changed), what is the most effective way to determine which one has the biggest dimensions?

Script:

```
Img1 = rgb2gray(imread('http://oi41.tinypic.com/2d9qx6o.jpg'));
size(Img1);
Img2 =  rgb2gray(imread('pillsetc.png'));
size(Img2);
Img3 =  rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));
size(Img3);
Img4 =  rgb2gray(imread('http://oi43.tinypic.com/239lhv.jpg'));
size(Img4);
Img5 =  (imread('rice.png'));
size(Img5);

A = [Img1 Img2 Img3 Img4 Img5];
max(A)
```

Comment: By dimensions, you mean the number of pixels in each direction? The total number of pixels? You can put all the sizes in a matrix and find the largest size and its index using the `max` function. Use `doc max` or `help max` to find more about how to use it.

Comment: Did you try anything before posting on here?

Comment: I wish to know which one as the biggest height and width so I can overly the other image on it. max will not help me in this case.

Comment: Your problem is ill-defined. What should you return if one image has a larger width while the other has a larger height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several approaches to determine which one "is bigger", or has the "max factor" :-)

```
images = {Img1, Img2, Img3, Img4, Img5};

[~, n_max_pixels]    = max(cellfun(@numel,         images));
[~, n_max_height]    = max(cellfun(@(x) size(x,1), images));
[~, n_max_width]     = max(cellfun(@(x) size(x,2), images));
[~, n_max_kewlness]  = max(cellfun(@(x) rand(1),   images));
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the output. e.g., how do i know which images as the biggest width and height. thanks

Comment: @user2613527 The output tells you which one of the images has: more pixels, bigger height, bigger width or is cooler. The returned numbers is the number of the picture. For example, if `n_max_height` is `3`, that means that `Img3` has the biggest height.

Comment: @user2613527 Also, may I ask why you downvoted my answer? Just curious. :-)

Comment: I did not down-voted your answer and somehow its ststus was returned to the original.

Comment: If I understand you correctly the highest image is Img1 but the output is Img4, am I missing something?

Comment: @user2613527 I assume that `Img1` .. `Img5` are m x n matrices of grayscale intensity (one number per pixel), where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns. In MATLAB one can get the number of rows (i.e. the height) from a matrix `x` with `size(x,1)`, and the number of columns (i.e. the width) with size(x,2). By the way, how did you determine that Img1 has the biggest height?

Comment: [height1, width1] = size(Img1);
[height4, width4] = size(Img4);

Comment: Then if the matrix Img1 has more rows than all Img2, Img3, Img4, Img5 matrices, the output should give n_max_height of value 1. Which version of MATLAB do you use?

Comment: Then the only thing that is passing trough my mind is: either the pictures are transposed, or you're running the `max` calculation on some old `Img` matrices that were not updated (see the first statement in the answer).

Comment: It is strange but I think it is related to the HTTP images. If I remove them it is fine.

Comment: How can I extract the image file name with the  n_max_width ?

Comment: @user2613527 unfortunately you can't directly from the images. but you can use the same trick: fnames = {'file1.jpg', 'some_other_file.jpg' ...}, and then you use: `fnames{n_max_width}` to get the file name